# rbenv Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2 but the only version installed is 2.1.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I'm using `rbenv` but I can run my server with: `rails s`
display me an error with:

> Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 2.1.2

I tried uninstall the version `2.0.0` but this version doesn't exist
`rbenv unistall 2.0.0`

And I tried with:
`rvm implode
-bash: rvm: command not found`
because I'm not using `rvm`, what I can do to run my server?

And my ruby  build says:

```
$ ruby-build --version
ruby-build 20141113
```

Comment: remove Gemfile.lock and run `bundle install`

Comment: I removed it, but the same message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to install Ruby 2.1.2. You can have multiple Ruby versions installed at the same time. If you have [ruby-build](https://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build) installed you can do the following: install 2.1.2, rehash your shims, and then tell rbenv to use 2.1.2 for this project.

```
rbenv install 2.1.2
rbenv rehash
rbenv local 2.1.2
```

You're going to have to gem install bundler and then bundle install on your project afterwards.

Comment: I just do these steps, but the problem persists

Comment: What does `ruby -v` return within the project root?

Comment: `ruby -v
ruby 2.1.2p95 (2014-05-08 revision 45877) [x86_64-darwin13.0]`